# Getting "param is missing or the value is empty: post" explained below

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when i click new post and try to save a new post it gives me that error, then i go to the controller :

```
private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end
```

and change 'require(:post)' to 'require(:posts' then i works
but then i try to edit the new post i just created and when i click to save it it gives me the same error, then i just change it back to 'required(:post)' and it works, why this is happening ? it's like a loop, if one works the other doesn't and to work i have to change that one thing

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def edit
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  @posts = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @posts.update(posts_params)
    redirect_to @posts
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  def new
    @posts = Post.new
  end

  def create
      @posts = Post.new(posts_params)
    if @posts.save
        redirect_to @posts
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @posts = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

view edit:

```
<h1>Editing post</h1>

<%= form_for(@posts)  do |f| %>

  <% if @posts.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@posts.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this post from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @posts.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

view new:

```
<h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for :posts, url: posts_path do |f| %>
<% if @posts.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@posts.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this post from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @posts.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

can someone point the problem out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing

```
form_for(@posts)  do |f|
```

and

```
 form_for :posts, url: posts_path
```

In your forms.

the `:posts` version will generate `params[:posts`] and the `@posts` version will generate `params[:post]`.  Hence the issue you are seeing. Make sure you posts_params is as follows.

```
def posts_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

then just change both of your forms to be

```
<%= form_for(@posts) do |f| %>
```

rails will figure out which to call automatically for you, so you will not have to specify the paths..

On a side note,  I would probably change `@posts` to be `@post` everywhere but the index action, just so that it makes more sense,  Since in new,edit,etc..  you are dealing with a singular post.

Since rails is looking at the Model/class of the variable when generating the routes (When given an instance variable) the name of the variable doesn't matter to the framework, but makes it easier (in my opinion) for the programmer to understand

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, and thanks for explaining so i can understand what this was causing and what i should do to fix it, so i can pay more attention in the future, nice answer